# I got two answers that I feel are of equal merit and answer the question... what do I do?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, accepted-answer

It appears that I can only accept a single answer but I really would like to reward the other answer-ers as well. I did give them an upvote but still I feel that there should be some mechanism to award both credit for giving a complete solution.

Also, want happens in the theoretical case where 2 answers both successfully answer your question and take different approaches, possibly both approaches being unknown to you? You certainly would want to award both responders for their effort and for the information you learned.

Can it be possible to accept multiple answers?

Comment: "Can it be possible to accept multiple answers?" - no, the system only supports accepting one answer. Toss a coin. ;)

Comment: It _is_ possible to issue [bounties](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8843/8348) to already posted answers.  And one can issue more than one bounty to any question.  Of course, this will _remove_ reputation from yourself, and one is quite limited in the amount of bounty to reward (50 is the least one can issue, if I recall correctly).  But I'm sure the answerers would appreciate your extra sacrifice! ;-)

Comment: @Arthur, if memory serves, there seems to be the snag of being able to offer only bounties of 100 rep and higher after offering a bounty of 50 rep. That puts a damper on the plan of rewarding both answers equally. Nevertheless, OP should still accept one of the two answers, if indeed they have helped him immensely.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks.  I forgot about that little detail.  As described in [this Meta StackOverflow answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/214632) subsequent bounties on the same question (by the same user) can only be made for double the previous amount, up to a maximum of 500.

Comment: I'm afraid you can only flip a coin, if you don't want to give away your reputation on bounties.

Comment: This is also related: [How do you accept the right answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/7131/how-do-you-accept-the-right-answer) and maybe some of the other answers linked there.

Comment: You can make it clear that you found both answers very helpful. That is much greater reward than $15$ points.